# Can I Mention Docker stop command in Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there any way to stop previous *docker container* inside *docker compose* file. 
Suppose below is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        build: .
        image: ${IMAGE_NAME}
        container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}
        ports:
              - 9020:9020
        volumes:
             - logs:logs
```

I want to add one step that can stop my old container and start a new one.
Please help me out.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/stop/ ?

Comment: Does using code formatting hurt? When seeking help, show us a minimum of respect and do it properly.

Comment: I don't remember seeing something like stopping the container with `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: You can't call a `script.sh` with your `docker-compose.yml` file that use `docker-compose stop` and launch the new one, but it's not very optimal